# Motivating the definition of the gauge covariant derivative from E&M

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, differentiation, gauge-invariance

Source: Faddeev and Salvnov's *Gauge Fields* page 4

> "The EM field interacts with charged fields, which are described by complex functions $\psi(x)$. In the equations of motion the field $A_\mu(x)$ always appears in the following combination:
>   $$
> \nabla_\mu \psi = (\partial_\mu - A_\mu) \psi = (\partial_\mu - iA_\mu) \psi."
> $$

I am trying to pedagogically justify the ansatz discussed in the following Wikipedia [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative#Construction_of_the_covariant_derivative_through_gauge_covariance_requirement) regarding the gauge covariant derivative from E&M as opposed to from gauge covariance.

As another example of this, Yang and Mill's original paper prefaces the covariant derivative with:

> "...we require, in analogy with the EM case, that all derivatives of $\psi$ appear in the following combination:
>   $$
> (\partial_\mu -ie B_\mu) \psi."
> $$

EDIT:

Very helpful hint into this via Griffith's *Elementary Particle Physics* textbook, page 360:

[image]

Comment: It's kind of buried, but maybe the discussion starting on (PDF) page 191 of these notes would help: https://www.pa.ucla.edu/faculty-websites/dhoker-lecture-notes/graduate-courses/qft-2016.pdf

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/520048/50583

Comment: Why do you say “as opposed to from gauge covariance”? That Wikipedia section is *about* gauge covariance.

Comment: @d_b I still can't find anything beyond "it's from QED" as is said on Wikipedia.
Prof. D'Hoker writes
"In QED, the ordinary derivative which appears in the kinetic term is upgraded to a covariant derivative which involves the gauge field $A_\mu$.

Comment: @G.Smith I mean that the form of the covariant derivative can be derived via an ansatz with the hindsight objective to satisfy gauge covariance. I am searching for a motivation from E&M for said form of the covariant derivative.

Comment: Related to @ACuriousMind's comment, I have edited the question to include a great hint in the direction to look next.